# Standard Json objects for different push notification services

Tags: json, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Is there actually a required json object which each push service requires. For example I always see the following in every tutorial:

Android:

```
var notification = "{\"data\":{\"msg\":\"Breaking " + category + " News!\"}}";
```

Apple:

```
var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Breaking " + category + " News!\"}}";
```

Do these structures have to be kept? or can I send my own custom objects down to the phone?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is quite specific to certain platform you are trying to send the Push Notification. If you want to just implement the GCM on standard Android Native App.. You can just embed the code in your server implementation.

```
 public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        // include config
        include_once './config.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }
```

So the answer to your question is No.